# Issues configuring strongSwan client on AWS instance for site-to-site VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I am trying to setup a IPSec VPN client on a debian-10 AWS instance.

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the VPN server as it is configured by another party, so all I know is they told me it is configured for my `my-aws-public-ip`.

I am trying to use a Strongswan - Linux strongSwan U5.7.2/K4.19.0-16-cloud-amd64

Here is my conf file:

```
config setup
        uniqueids=no
        charondebug="all"

conn vpn
        type=tunnel
        keyexchange=ikev2
        aggressive=no
        authby=secret
        auto=add
        ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048!
        esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048!
        ikelifetime=28800s
        left=my-aws-internal-ip
        leftid=my-aws-public-ip
        leftsubnet=192.168.140.120/29
        leftsourceip=192.168.140.121
        right=another-party-peer-ip
        rightsubnet=another-party-tunnel-network/mask
        dpddelay=300s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart
        rekey=yes
        reauth=yes
        keylife=3600s
        closeaction=restart
        encap=yes
        forceencaps=yes
        installpolicy=yes
```

When I `sudo systemctl restart strongswan`, I get an active service. However, it seems I am not part of the VPN as I can not ping any of the `another-party-tunnel-network` ip addresses.

**Using an elastic IP on AWS, I presume I am behind a NAT. Is that a problem for transfering packages through the IPSec tunnel?**

**Do you see something wrong with my conf file?**

Last but not least, when I was told by the other party that they have configured the VPN for my-aws-public-ip, I received a file with information about the network - like the IKE Version, Authenticaiton Mode, Preshared Key, etc. I have inserted the Preshared key in /etc/ipsec.secrets using the following syntax: `: PSK "my-preshared-key"`
Additionally in the file with network information, it is said that they have configured VPN Tunnel Access List Information for the network: 192.168.140.120/29, and Firewall security rules for 192.168.140.121, hence I added `leftsubnet` and `leftsourceip` in the config file. **This is not my AWS subnet. Is that an issue?** I have added an interface with `sudo ip address add 192.168.140.121/29 dev ens5`,  and I see it with `ip a`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: With `auto=add` the connection is not automatically initiated. Either change that to `start` or `route` or use `sudo ipsec up vpn` to initiate the connection manually. Also note that `leftsourceip` is for dynamically negotiating virtual IPs, it's not necessary for static internal IPs, `leftsubnet` is enough for that.